# Laravel Blade Foreach Loop Takes upto 18sec to load 100 data

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

Am still pretty new to laravel but there's some very weird issue am facing.
In the Laravel blade view file. It take some crazy amount of seconds to load content to the browser using Foreach method

This is from the admin section controller

```
$rates = Rate::where('user_id',  $user->user_id)
                        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                        ->paginate(100);
return view('admin.users-view', compact('headers', 'rates'));
```

The query takes about 2sec or less

On the Blade file, the foreach takes about 18sec to display this to the browser and gives me a crazy headache. Please may I know what am doing wrong?

```
@foreach ($rates as $rate)
        <td>{{ data('days', $rate->lead_time) }}</td>
        <td>{{ data('kg', $rate->weight) }}</td>
        <td>{{ data('format', $rate->dropoff) }}</td>
        <td>{{ $rate->tax }}</td>
        <td>{{ date("d M Y", strtotime($rate->created_at)) }}</td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="fetchRate(this)" id="{{ $rate->id }}" 
                class="edit link" 
                content="{{ json_encode($rate) }}">
                {{ Get_Lang('update', Get_Lang_Cookie()) }}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="deleteRate(this)"
                    id="{{ $rate->id }}" class="edit link">
                {{ Get_Lang('delete', Get_Lang_Cookie()) }}
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Rate Table Structure

```
Schema::create('rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->index();
    $table->string('origin', 5);
    $table->string('destination', 5);
    $table->string('lead_time')->nullable();
    $table->string('weight');
    $table->string('dropoff')->default(0); //price amount
    $table->string('tax')->default(0);
    $table->timestamp('created_at', 0)->nullable()->index();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at', 0)->nullable();
});
```

Comment: show the structure of the table

Comment: Try removing this piece `{{ json_encode($rate) }}` and see if the load speed changes

Comment: Have actually removed that already and same issue. In fact, the issue is with almost all my views wherever I have to use the foreach to load content into the browser.

Comment: and add `<tr>` at the beginning of foreach

Comment: That was a mistake from the code I paste here also.

Comment: How big is the html document as a result? (you can see in your browser dev tools->network)

Comment: 181 kB transferred
179 kB resources
Finish: 13.12 s
DOMContentLoaded: 12.84 s
Load: 13.10 s

Comment: I don't think `@foreach` is the problem. How much would the timing change if you commented out the entire `@foreach` block in the template?

Comment: 1.6 MB transferred
1.6 MB resources
Finish: 5.70 s
DOMContentLoaded: 3.32 s
Load: 5.66 s

With the foreach commented out

Comment: It is not clear why the document size increased almost 10 times after commenting. I suggest you install debugbar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see what happens to your application during the query.

Comment: Thanks alot. Without the foreach the entire application runs in at most:

1 x Application (53.08%) 
1.09s
1 x Booting (46.9%) 
965.84ms

The moment I need to use the foreach to output all data, then page extreme load delay starts.

using Laravel: ^9.3.8